# Change <option value> with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I need a select with this

```
  { id: 111, shortName: 'RJ' },
  { id: 112, shortName: 'MG' },
  { id: 113, shortName: 'DF' }
```

I need to show the 'shortName' field on the selector, but the  needs to be with the id value. This is what I have:

```
<select ng-model="model.StateId" ng-options="c.shortName for c in model.states"></select>
```

It shows the shortName correctly, but the option values are 0, 1, 2. How can I modify them with the id value on the array?

Answer (score 3):

The ng options should be like this:

ng-options="c.id as c.shortName for c in model.states">

The following is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/kuKO5eZn10Cpe1DQEQPr?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<select ng-model="model.StateId" ng-options="c.id as c.shortName for c in model.states"></select>
```

That is `ng-options = select as label for value in array`

[AngularJS select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)